# How to make 0 display as 0.00 using decimal format?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am using the following code to make numbers display with two decimal places and thousands comma separator.

```
public static String formatNumber(double amount){
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
    return formatter.format(amount);
}
```

For other numbers it is ok but 0 is returned as ".00" I want it to be "0.00" What should I change?

Comment: how about `"#,##0.00"`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought you were swearing for second there ;)

Comment: Also, the separator I think can be automatically set via `setGroupingUsed(true)`. This way you will automatically have the separator show for thousands, millions, billions, ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why not

```
return String.format("%.2f", amount);
```

That would format it correctly wouldn't it? (if amount is 123123.14233 then it would return 123123.14)

or

```
return String.format("%,.2f", amount);
```

for commas within the number. (if amount is 123123.14233 then it would return 123,123.14)

Answer (score 23):

The `#` means optional digit, so if you use `0` instead it will work:

```
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");
```

BTW: I think you need 3 `###` not 4.